# Зацикливание таймера

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня в админке есть 2 поля: `Время(тип дата-время)` и `Повтор(типа чексбокс)`.

Я устанавливаю время до которого должен работать таймер, например, сейчас `22:00`, устанавливаю `22:10`, на сайте начинается обратный отсчет `10` минут. Когда `10` минут заканчивается, таймер пропадает. А я хочу, что если включена кнопка `Повтор`, то после истечения `10` минут, таймер снова уходил на отсчет `10` минут и так до бесконечности. Возможно ли такое сделать с текущим кодом?
Я могу выводить кусок кода в зависимости от условия, только не могу понять, как этот таймер зациклить.

```js
var datetime = $('#countdown-1').data('value');
var countDownDate = new Date(datetime);

// обновление каждую секунду
var x = setInterval(function() {

    // текущее время
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    
    // время, оставшееся до окончания отсчета
    var distance = countDownDate - now ;

    // вычисление дней, часов, минут и секунд

    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    

    // вывод времени в элемент с ID "countdown"
    document.getElementById("countdown-1").innerHTML =  hours + "ч "
        + minutes + "м ";
    
    // если отсчет закончился, остановка таймера
    if (distance < 0) {
        clearInterval(x);
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Проверяйте в вашем блоке `distance < 0`, что стоит галочка, если стоит, то изменяйте `countDownDate`, берете текущую дату и прибавляете 10 минут. (или же при первом запуске определяйте разницу и потом ее прибавляйте).

Comment: спасибо! Добавил countDownDate.setMinutes(countDownDate.getMinutes() + 1440 ); и таймер стал зацикливаться на 24 часа, потом сделаю чтобы высчитывалась изначальная разница